# what the numbers in the array indicate?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, spl-token-program, instructions, decode

I work with decoding data. I use the `@solana/spl-token` package for that.

sometimes I get the **TokenInvalidInstructionKeysError** error

I have this code ts. as keys I provide an array of keys that I have selected by index from the message.accountKeys array

```
import { decodeInstruction } from '@solana/spl-token'

    const decodeDataTokenProgram = decodeInstruction({
      keys: instruction.keys, // keys corresponding to the index from message.accountKeys
      programId: instruction.programId,
      data: instruction.data
    })
```

I read that document, but I'm not quite sure what they mean https://solana.com/ru/docs/rpc/json-structures

according to the documentation: **accounts: <array[number]> - List of ordered indices into the message.accountKeys array indicating which
accounts to pass to the program.**

the indices are there. But what about the last index? For example, there is index 22, but we will get undefined by this index. Does it mean that if we get the last index, we should always take -1 and we will get index 21. It's a bit misleading, to be honest.

**I posted the raw data for you to look at.** https://pastebin.com/a32KZ55E

**please give me an example of how I can use addressTableLookups to decode an instruction**

Using this data as an example, please show me how to work with an array of accounts

```
    "transaction": {
        "message": {
            "accountKeys": [
                "3cSSMT43FQCgBAT4KCxJsUULFy9P258AUdnvwK76dvkB",
                "E8M7hoiYsJZnwhML1Q7ot6S73mcW6qfoEyUuFtGvmepU",
                "6GvCe4zhWwQqToG7jPrVaoBXRNhn7aT99gG4QZas8kYf",
                "GWnZKcgBq55K2WaBEFmiuv8Gcq9siySYpu4A24uPAcCH",
                "8P7hQpgn4v2HPSyDkX9VJVVExQ5S1sf3YQEMHcg8HoLv",
                "4F86x89wFGmRg8RtYA1zwkR7xdooim5g9eS6ZF6TYhcF",
                "FeY3rti4By34aE61qCNL9MnWGBPT2o8LM2gzYEMtemzp",
                "2bmzR5tAUWUXCFJvvoWPw5nacVdES7Qw1TtgkEAdXv37",
                "9iq7ewwfRAXUYZ6ZgStSa6SDhQ5h3uudM6et22FX6FDT",
                "GzgjLJQuu3TNeJi9B242huJVTDoJwueTHuAbSQjrEBm6",
                "AXMjwxHaWj9rYQ12PhTVnqVnT3hCtcT53ejGVaLMNT9p",
                "ER7bFuygbrTiw3s1gmQrLmZJSzGA38kbf22NfJH7kbtK",
                "Ck3T2nRCFK4CRKhMsGa14oNPcsdJrf8a6EKpeY7BDenU",
                "F9Jcfi17FSzbNrpZ1pvcGrXUi57PvWz36LDMj9yQnDhn",
                "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
                "34geSnvYBUfqthfSRjMW2iByt2egMrqJ49wpixYE3pem",
                "11111111111111111111111111111111",
                "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                "4PGwUH7o4xoePV6xpAXCLQp2LBDnLjpyJTXEch1t81Tj",
                "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
                "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL",
                "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8"
            ],
            "addressTableLookups": [
                {
                    "accountKey": "FUigYUS3EPJB682u6mCgvox7JMfHn6KxqhYdnLmqm2pe",
                    "readonlyIndexes": [4, 21,20],
                    "writableIndexes": []
                }
            ],

         "header": {
            "numReadonlySignedAccounts": 0,
            "numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts": 8,
            "numRequiredSignatures": 2
            },
        "instructions": [
            {
              "accounts":[ 1, 14, 0, 22 ],
              "data": "2",
              "programIdIndex": 17
            },
         ]
        },
        "signatures": [
"264LHUKwinwdKRN5i3VDHfzjz1ffxv1yD6wE3JEnDsSoFTCgz6bWwVfmmBW1b3HKE5ptKdAr43qokY9hxRWZ1YcY",
"3p7eAciagCWcDX5hzwr6gz5waNQUvPuZCCe4YPVhLvHvsGM6F8Tnmwhj5xwjx7NEAo8gVzzT8WSxDGpuKoeGiK3J"
        ]
     },
       "version": 0
    }
```

In this instruction, the last element of the accounts array is 22. If we rely on this number, the index from accountKeys will return undefined.

please tell me how to work with this instruction? in the context of decodeInstuction function from @solana/spl-token

**update.** i added an array of addressTableLookups.Question how to work with this array? the documentation gives examples of how to create it, not how to work with it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This transaction is using an address from a lookup table.

You will need to set the request parameters  `encoding` to json and the `maxSupportedTransactionVersion` to 0 in the `getTransaction` request .

And the full list of account meta will be available.

Comment: thank you. Yes I am getting version 0 data. there is an addressTableLookups array. I was reading the documentation and I didn't understand how to get data from this array. The documentation only talks about creating such tables

Comment: There’s additional data in the response and the field name is transaction.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand you. I added the data I get, could you show me more clearly how to connect this instruction and the addressTableLookups array? thanks

Comment: What’s your parameters for the getTransaction request?

Comment: I get this data in raw form from the helius webhook.

Comment: I could add all the data from the transaction, but it would take up a lot of space, so I tried to add all the necessary information. tell me if anything is missing.

Comment: So I'm not sending an rpc request, I'm getting the data from the webhook in raw form.

Comment: What kind of webhook are you using?

Comment: I use: webhook type = raw, mainnet

Comment: I posted the raw data for you to look at. You can evaluate at the link above, in the post. thanks

Comment: Use the loadedAddresses field. Append the array to accountKeys

Comment: you mean add the values from the loadedAddresses array to the end of the accountKeys array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151014/discussion-between-wei1769-and-slntrx).